# Physical response to threatening behavior - still self-defense?

Tags: germany, self-defense

Assuming the following scenario: "I" asked a visitor to my home to return an item they had borrowed some time earlier. In response, they got angry and crowded me into a corner, acting very threateningly. After trying to calm them down, I shoved them backwards to get out of the disadvantageous position. This lead to them hitting me, which I was able to stop by picking up a household item that could be weaponised.

They do not want to press charges, but claim that I assaulted them, citing my supposed physical superiority and use of "weapons".

Did I not act in self-defense because I used direct physical force first?

Comment: *This lead to them hitting me, which I was able to stop* - does it mean they hit you one or more times and were going to continue but were subsequently dissuaded from doing so by your picking up a "weapon" ? Or does it mean that they demonstrated intent to hit you but actually hit you 0 times as a result of you picking up a weapon?

Comment: Given the scenario, the attacker did hit several times, to which "I" picked up the item (nothing inherently dangerous like a knife) to dissuade them from continuing - not in a clear threat, but more like "Stop, or this escalates further."

Comment: The argument is that my initial shove triggered the fight, not the threatening behaviour: "If you were afraid for your safety, why push it over the edge so that it actually becomes a physical fight? Hence you attacked and didn't act in self-defense." That's what I am pondering with regards to the usual "reasonably believes it immediately is necessary to prevent the unlawful use of force against themselves or a third party" - the other person in this case claims "my" defense actually created the situation in which physical force was an option.